# Media con pandas Series

Tags: python

Tengo una Series de pandas sacada de un groupby que cuenta el numero de partidos jugados por año de esta forma:

```
serie

year
1993      8
1994     29
1995     33
1996     36
1997     39
1998     20
1999     43
2000     41
...      ...
```

tengo que hacer la media de partidos para cada año

Answer (score 0):

Nada, se hace mucho mas simple de lo que pensaba:

```
serie/len(serie)
```

Comment: Hola Jose, me alegro que encontraras una solución a tu problema. ¿Podrías añadir una descripción de lo que hace ese código? Saludos